# .net 6 BuildServiceProvider is missing

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

net 6, create console application with 'minimal template'. try add DI but BuildServiceProvider is missing. I try google about how migrate ServiceCollection but did not find nothing.

```
var services2 = new ServiceCollection();
var serviceProvider = services2.BuildServiceProvider();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package?

Comment: yes type serviceCollection is resolve okey without error. 
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Comment: Having the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: I found out the solution.
You have to explicitly install the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection NuGet, even if you're referencing the correct one from the start.
In my case was version 6.0.0.

Comment: Did you guys isntall the package from VS nuget package manager?

Comment: Case of elements of the namespace being avilable gobally, but that doesn't mean the functions are.

Answer (score 21):

In my idiotic case, I was using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. I didn't notice at first because `ServiceCollection`, `AddSingleton` etc were available using the first NuGet as well. Icon and author are the same for both NuGets.

Comment: Run into absolutely same situation, because my IDE imported `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Answer (score 5):

The following two steps fixed it for me (VS2022, .NET Standard 2.0):

1. Make sure all your projects are referring to the same version of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. At the time of this writing, the latest version is `7.0.0`. You can use **Consolidate** tab in solution's Nuget Configuration page to achieve this.
2. Go to project's Nuget Configuration page (and not Solution's Nuget Configuration page) by right-clicking the problematic project and choosing **Manage Nuget Packages**. Therein, uninstall `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and then re-install it (again making sure you're using the same version as other projects in the solution).

Rebuild the solution after this and things should look good.